# How to add Python data to HTML table

Tags: python, html, django, data-structures, html-table

I need to have following table format in HTML:
[image]

My question is, how I should organize my Python data correctly so that I can implement this following table format in a clean, Pythonic way. All images belong to the certain version, thus it's important that image is in the right column (order matters). And some versions don't have all (or any) images so in that case, I'll check if "image == None" and show "?" etc. instead of the image. Thus, also 'empty' slots should be saved to data.

Note: I'm doing this with Django and I use Django templates to render this. Ideally, I could do something like following in the template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for version in data.versions %}
      <th>{{ version }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for image in data.images %}
    <tr>
      {% for file in image.files %}
        {% if file == None %}
        <td>No image</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{ file }}</td>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Update: the problem is really how to organize data correctly in the backend. I need to manually initialize a list of versions (Version1, Version2, etc.) I want to put to data and create columns for those. Ordering is important so I need to keep that. Then I'll search for certain Objects which have X amount of images, which all have a certain version. Then I need to loop over those objects (for object in objects) and loop over images of the certain object (for image in object.images) and I should append each image to the column of certain version (add to column where "key" etc. == image.version). If there is no image for certain column, then value should be "None" etc.

I could implement this with list of lists for example:

```
data = [
    ['Version1', 'Version2', etc.],
    ['image',None, etc.],
    ['image', 'image', etc.],
    etc.
]
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a better way to implement that in Python. So any better suggestions are very welcome.

Update 2: Django models could be like following:

```
class Version(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version)


class Object(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
```

Comment: What's wrong with having list of lists?

Comment: @elena Nothing wrong but in my case, I'd rather have the data in a format which allows me to use "data.versions", "image.files" etc. in layout code. I just think it's more readable and maintainable that way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`data_versions = { v1 : [img1, img2 ...], v2: [img1, ....]}`

Comment: I updated the question, I think it is now more clear what is the problem. Could you check if it helps to give more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way. 
First create a Model (database table) for your data and store everything there. You will have more power in representation of your data that way.

**Models.py**

```
class VersionImage(models.Model):
    version_number = models.IntegerField()
    image_1 = models.ImageField()
    image_2 = models.ImageField()
    image_3 = models.ImageField()
```

(I'm making a lot of assumptions on what your data looks like, so might want to change these based on your needs)

A better option (if you're going to have an array of images) would be to store all Images in one model, and make a M2M to your version table:

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()

class VersionModel(models.Model):
    version_number = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ManyToManyField(ImageModel)
```

Then you can put the logic you want on the "Form/View" before sending it to your HTML template.

When working with Django, try to put everything on the backend and use HTML just for rendering the data that is already sorted and ready to present.

Let me know if you want me to elaborate on any of the above.

Comment: Thanks, I just added my current database model related to this questions. Now I just should find a way to put that data to format which allows me to loop over it in template, without need of any further logic. As you said, I don't want to have any logic in layouts.